# Blank page with Symfony2 app

Tags: apache, symfony, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have just deployed my Symfony2-based app on an AWS account (on a EC2 instance using Ubuntu 16.04) after setting up the web environment (Apache2, MySQL, PHP7). The Ubuntu /var/www/html/index.html default file is rendered properly. But when it comes to Symfony2, I'm having a blank page both with app.php and app_dev.php. When I test with Filezilla debug tool, I can see the "500 Internal Server Error" error message appearing. The Symfony2 config.php indicates that everything is fine now, I had just to add the date.timezone value on php.ini. My .htaccess files are well configured since I'm using the same model that is working on other Symfony2-based websites I set up before.

This is what I have on /logs/dev.log:

```
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:23:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-27 18:39:22] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:05] php.DEBUG: The Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DebugHandlerPass class is deprecated since version 2.12 and will be removed in 3.0. Use AddDebugLogProcessorPass in FrameworkBundle instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/DebugHandlerPass.php","line":14,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Passing a string as the $source argument of Twig_Environment::tokenize() is deprecated since version 1.27. Pass a Twig_Source instance instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":604,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Defining the initRuntime() method in the "form" extension is deprecated since version 1.23. Use the `needs_environment` option to get the Twig_Environment instance in filters, functions, or tests; or explicitly implement Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface if needed (not recommended). {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php","line":794,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in WebProfilerBundle:Collector:form.html.twig at line 611. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 205. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 323. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 325. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 337. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 339. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 351. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] php.DEBUG: Twig Test "sameas" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use "same as" instead in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 353. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php","line":646,"level":4352} []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-11-28 00:44:06] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

I also checked /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Mon Nov 28 06:25:02.181251 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13742] AH00163: Apa$
[Mon Nov 28 06:25:02.181268 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13742] AH00094: Command li$
[Mon Nov 28 09:34:27.731905 2016] [:error] [pid 18830] [client 41.251.22.4:4926$
[Mon Nov 28 09:34:27.732394 2016] [:error] [pid 18830] [client 41.251.22.4:4926$
[Mon Nov 28 09:35:51.425233 2016] [:error] [pid 18832] [client 41.251.22.4:5048$
[Mon Nov 28 09:38:09.621647 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5103$
[Mon Nov 28 09:38:09.621901 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5103$
[Mon Nov 28 09:46:16.528434 2016] [:error] [pid 18831] [client 41.251.22.4:2130$
[Mon Nov 28 09:46:16.528644 2016] [:error] [pid 18831] [client 41.251.22.4:2130$
[Mon Nov 28 09:48:41.956055 2016] [:error] [pid 18832] [client 41.251.22.4:5224$
[Mon Nov 28 09:48:41.956345 2016] [:error] [pid 18832] [client 41.251.22.4:5224$
[Mon Nov 28 09:49:06.614155 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5228$
[Mon Nov 28 09:49:06.614356 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5228$
[Mon Nov 28 10:07:58.290011 2016] [:error] [pid 18831] [client 41.251.22.4:5284$
[Mon Nov 28 10:07:58.290215 2016] [:error] [pid 18831] [client 41.251.22.4:5284$
[Mon Nov 28 10:09:25.032732 2016] [:error] [pid 21233] [client 41.251.22.4:5287$
[Mon Nov 28 10:09:25.032947 2016] [:error] [pid 21233] [client 41.251.22.4:5287$
[Mon Nov 28 10:09:44.034353 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5288$
[Mon Nov 28 10:09:44.034556 2016] [:error] [pid 18829] [client 41.251.22.4:5288$
```

Any clues on how I can use these information to resolve my issue, especially on logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this issue by running app/console assets:install and clearing cache in dev environment (app/console cache:clear). Then, I had to deal with the following exception:

> RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 239: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/app/cache/dev/classes.php".

Which I reserve by following the instructions provided here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/file_permissions.html

For Linux system:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*    

$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|

[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
# if this doesn't work, try adding `-n` option
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```